# Actual position of view not changing after setfillafter(true) in android animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

I am moving the view via this code, but the actual position of view is not changed, why

```
                TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -mbar4.getHeight());
                ta.setDuration(1000);
                ta.setFillAfter(true);
                v4.startAnimation(ta);
```

Answer (score 3):

up to version 3 (API 11) of android excluding , all animations don't really change the view , only the way it is shown . not only that, but i think they don't use the GPU at all.

in order to check it out , you can use a button and setOnClickListener for it , and see that no matter which animation you use , the click will work only on its original position and size.

here's a sample code of moving a view using the translateAnimation:

```
final int deltaXToMove=50;
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0,deltaXToMove,0,0);
int animationTime=1000;
translateAnimation.setDuration(animationTime);
translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
  {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams par=(LayoutParams)b.getLayoutParams();
    par.leftMargin=deltaXToMove;
    b.setLayoutParams(par);
    }
...
b.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. The actual position is not changed, I wonder whats the use of setfillafter then.

Comment: in my opinion , the whole animation features up to android 3 (excluding) is very weird and almost useless . it's only useful for simple things , like transitions , and animations of items that come and go (for example, to the listView) .

Comment: The above one is not working...Please see this video its the basic problem i am facing, the listview move upwards, but when i scroll the traces of previous view come over it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcKpJu8zWe8&feature=relmfu

Comment: why did you use an animation here? is it because i mentined the listview ? i meant that it's for the items in it , when they are created , not when they need to scroll . for scrolling , simply use smoothScrollBy or something similar : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollBy(int, int)

Comment: this works, and it does make sense, BUT, there's a flickering effect happening when the view animation uses FillAfter(false), as it is send back to original position, while the view itself is moved to the new position. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: well it was a long time since i've answered this answer , so i don't remember what it is about and i can't watch the video . i'm guessing you set an animation for a view within a listview in order to show it is removed . for this there are already built in animations (which you can change) and it's called "layoutAnimation" .

Answer (score 0):

Because TranslateAnimation only changes where the View is drawn.

Try this:

```
    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -mbar4.getHeight());
    ta.setDuration(1000);
    ta.setFillAfter(true);
    ta.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v4.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = mbar4.getHeight();
            v4.requestLayou();
        }
    });
    v4.startAnimation(ta);
```

Change RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to whatever the parent Layout is.